# Sublime Text 2 Mac Markdown Preview Keybinding

Tags: macos, markdown, key-bindings, sublimetext

I am having some difficulty setting a simple keybinding in Sublime Text 2, which I have only been using for a few hours.

I managed to install [Markdown Preview](https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview) and learned how to invoke it on a simple markdown text file.  My next desire was to set a simple key binding to bring up the browser preview without having to go through the Command Palette, which I find a bit cumbersome.

The instructions at the above link are fairly clear, and I managed to modify my User Settings as directed, so that they look like this:

```
// Settings in here override those in "Default/Preferences.sublime-settings", and
// are overridden in turn by file type specific settings.
{
    "keys": ["alt+m"], 
        "command": "markdown_preview", 
        "args": 
            {
                "target": "browser"
            }
}
```

For some reason, however, ALT-m is not bringing up the preview.  Instead, the greek letter mu gets inserted into my text file.

I assumed this is because of some peculiarity involving the Option key on a Mac, so I experimented with trying to bind it to another key like "f7", but that doesn't seem to work either.

Can anybody think of any gotchas involving keybindings for Sublime Text 2 on MacOS X that I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User keybindings are defined in the `.sublime-keymap` file, I think you are in the `.sublime-settings file`. Just put it in the right file and it should work. I'm on Windows, so I'm not sure if it's identical for Mac, but I can access the file from the Preferences menu (Key Bindings - User).

Comment: You nailed it, thank you.  I was editing the settings file instead of the keymap file by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I 'd like to add something,  sublime text2, and os x 10.8

Check the following picture, go to the Menu of sublime text 2,  `Sublime Text 2` -> `Preference` -> `Key Binds Default` -  and then in the file do the edit for need,

[image]